# Responsive div ordering

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to improve a web page. The layout is currently like this. The numbers represent the divs that I am trying to manipulate.

[image: current layout]

I want to make the web responsive, and the new layout that I'm trying to achieve this layout. The problem that I'm currently having is that `div 4` and `div 5` is inside `div 3`, so I can't put `div 4` above everything without having `div 5` positioned below it.

[image: desired layout]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: you need to go code based adaptive layout technique, dynamically remove the div tag and add between `div 4` an `div 5` you can use jQuery or even normal javascript, otherwise keep a hidden div tag between `div 4` and `div 5` and make it visible via media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As div 3 likely appears to only serve as a container I've removed it as it inhibits a simple layout and structurally it likely can be placed above div-4 for static content. Feel free to ask with more details if div-3 is a requirement for a particular goal.

Essentially floats will try to fill the space in a given container with a few rules. We can use `float: right;` in conjunction with a media query to achieve the desired result. The main caveat is that #div-2 must be taller than #div-4 otherwise it may cause some layout related issues - specifying an appropriate min-height will help here. Essentially the below example is your typical responsive layout but it uses float left and right as well as strategically planned markup to order/reorder the elements as you desired.

When floated left - all elements display in order they appear.
When 4 and 5 are floated right div 2 takes up 66% and 4 and 5 float right to fill the remaining 33%.

```css
div{
  min-height: 50px; 
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#div-1{
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 720px){
  #div-2{
    width: 66.6%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #div-4, #div-5{
    float: right; 
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <div id="div-4">4</div>
  <div id="div-2">2</div>
  <div id="div-5">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced almost similar situation and solved it following these steps:

1. Copy the divs separately in a new html page (just for rough
   purposes, we will delete this page later).
2. Make sure that all divs are now independent of each other.
3. Import bootstrap(https://getbootstrap.com/)
4. Now create a bootstrap table using the class .table and assign col-md-**x** to each row. (Replace the value of x with the width you want for each div)

For example, if you require only 2 div with the first div as the largest one, you can use this code:

```
<tr class="something">
    <td class="col-md-8">A</td>
    <td class="col-md-4">B</td>
</tr>
```